# pygtk: imported but not used?

Tags: python, pygtk

Here is a example on the pygtk website:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # example base.py
    import pygtk
    pygtk.require('2.0')
    import gtk

    class Base:
        def __init__(self):
            self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
            self.window.show()

        def main(self):
            gtk.main()

    print __name__
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        base = Base()
        base.main()
```

pygtk is imported  but used nowhere, why?

Comment: Does the program work if you remove it?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer in the FAQs of pygtk: http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq02.004.htp

This import is only necessary if you have installed multiple versions of gtk and want to be sure that the "right" version (the version you want) will be imported. Alternatively the version which you have installed at last will be used.